# Unable to get Youtube stats (views) with Google API SDK or with just key

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, google-api-php-client

I am trying to access the numbers of views from my youtube videos. I used to use the v2 of the Google API for Youtube stats. But for some reason nothing I try works.

First I tried using the API Explorer given by Google. It worked... It generated this request:

GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reports?ids=channel%3D%3DU9999999&start-date=2015-05-01&end-date=2015-05-01&metrics=views&dimensions=video&filters=video%3D%3D6cBs8212oyI&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

So I tried it in curl with the key I created in Google API Console I also activated Youtube API and Youtube API Stats...

But when I curl it I get this error:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Login Required",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Login Required"
 }
}
```

I have no idea what this means...

So now I tried with Google SDK.

I am able to get this:

```
{
 "access_token":"--------",
 "expires_in":3600,
 "created":1431449678
}
```

But then I get this error:

> **Fatal error:** Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with
>   message 'Error calling GET
>   https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=channel%3D%0000000&start-date=2015-05-01&end-date=2015-05-01&metrics=views&filters=video%3D%3D6cBs8212oyI:
>   (403) Insufficient Permission' in
>   /------/google-api-php-client/src/Google/Http/REST.php:111
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /--------/google-api-php-client/src/Google/Http/REST.php(63):
>   Google_Http_REST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(Google_Http_Request),
>   Object(Google_Client)) #1 [internal function]:
>   Google_Http_REST::doExecute(Object(Google_Client),
>   Object(Google_Http_Request)) #2
>   /--------/google-api-php-client/src/Google/Task/Runner.php(172):
>   call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #3
>   /--------/google-api-php-client/src/Google/Http/REST.php(47):
>   Google_Task_Runner->run() #4
>   /------/google-api-php-client/src
>   in
>   **/-------/google-api-php-client/src/Google/Http/REST.php**
>   on line **111**

So this seems to be the issue:

> (403) Insufficient Permission

I tried to find what was causing this but to no avail.

Again this requests works in Google explorer found on this page: https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/

Here is the code I use for requesting my Youtube views:

```
try {

    $key = file_get_contents($key_file_location);

    if( $key === false )
        throw new Exception('Failed to open/read p12 key file.');

    $cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
        $service_account_name,
        array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics.readonly'),
        $key
    );

    $client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);

    // Check if the token is out of date
    if ($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($cred);
    }

    // Reset the service_token in the PHP session
    echo $_SESSION['service_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();

} catch (Exception $e) {
    //getStatsMailError( 'Caught exception: ' . $e->getMessage() );
    error_log($e->getMessage());
}

//Option Paramaters
$optParams = array(
    'filters'       => 'video==6cBs8212oyI',
);

$result = $service->data_ga->get($channel_id, '2015-05-01', '2015-05-01', 'views', $optParams);
```

The rest works because I am able to get the access_token.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use a service account, which the YouTube APIs don't support. You'll have to set up a server-side or client-side oAuth flow to authorize the scopes and get your access token (along with a refresh token so you can get new access tokens when needed): https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication#server-side-apps is where to start. The PHP client should also be able to support the whole oAuth flow as well.

Comment: I did that. I got my client id, secret, etc... It only gives me the token.